# How to create a job in SharePoint Central Administrator 2010 using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I am new to SharePoint and Visual Studio.

1. I read some articles, regarding my topic. I understood,for creating 
   jobs in SharePoint, we have to use the Visual Studio then we have to create SharePoint 2010 or 2013 empty SharePoint project.
2. But I look in to my client Remote desktop. It has SharePoint 2010
   and Visual Studio 2008, but does not have SharePoint server. Wwhen I
   try to create a new project, it does not contain SharePoint template
   in that. But lot of jobs already been created in Central
   Administrator. How it has been created. I wish to know about this.
   Is there any other way to create jobs in central administrator?
3. SharePoint Server is essential for the templates to show in Visual
   Studio? Is there any possibility add SharePoint server to installed 
   SQL Server Management Studio?

Please provide documentation links to understand those things.

Comment: you can create timer jobs for your requirement.  "Is there any possibility add SharePoint server to installed SQL Server Management Studio?"" what do you mean by this statement? the statement is very much confusing

Comment: share point tools has been installed during installation of sql server or else once i installed sql server with skip of share point,how could I install share point ?

Comment: @SaMolPP for creating timer jobs...i need sharepoint template in my visual studio...it's the right one...sorry for asking again..

Answer (score 0):

Start from the basic understand what is SharePoint server and SQL both are different concept, but when you learn more about SharePoint eventually SQL server, content DB part will be understand.
In central administration that jobs you have seen already some jobs that are provided by default.